# What is the CoCo "Head Banger bug" and what is the "fix"?

Tags: color-computer, bugs

I remember that horrible racket coming from the floppy disk when I first used it after started my CoCo, and that it was called the "Head Banger bug".

I remember that it was due to a quick-n-nasty bit of code by the original designers – but what was the story again?

I also remember that there was a "Head Banger bug fix" – but what was it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I posted this question because I had those thoughts, and then spent ages going through multiple dead ends until I finally found it (my Google-fu is on the fritz). So that I don't have to go through that again...

According to an article by Marty Goodman in the July 1983 issue of [Hot CoCo](http://sparksandflames.com/files/HotCoCo-1983-07.pdf#page=48):

> #### The Head-Banger Bug
>
> You may have noticed that just after power up or after a cold start, when you ask the disk to load a file, the drive will almost always make a very nasty rattling noise before loading the file. By an oversight in the Disk Basic, the software "thinks" that the head is at track 0 at power up. Actually, the head is usually not at track 0, but is wherever it was when you shut down the system. Often this is track 17 (directory track).
>
> Because of this, when the software tries to go to track 17 to search for the
> file you asked the disk to load, it "thinks" it is starting at track 0 and
> runs off into the inner edge of the drive. It does recover after banging itself
> against a mechanical stop, but this banging is not good for the drive.

And later on in the article:

> You can get around the head-banger bug by typing "EXEC &HDCCG" [sic] after power up and cold starts. This resets the head to track 0.

Yes, it had the nonsense value of `&HDCCG`. The mistake was later corrected in the [September 1983 issue of Hot CoCo, page 12](http://www.colorcomputerarchive.com/coco/Documents/Magazines/Hot%20CoCo%20(Searchable%20image)/Hot%20Coco%20Vol.%201%20No.%204%20-%20September%201983.pdf#page=12) to `&HD66C`.

[Disk Basic Unravelled](http://roust-it.dk/coco/disk-basic-unravelled.pdf) says `$D66C` is DSKCON in the 1.0 version of the ROM.  Presumably one would call `$D75F` in the 1.1 version of the ROM if the head-banger bug is even in that version.

Comment: According to the [disk basic unravelled](http://www.colorcomputerarchive.com/coco/Documents/Books/Unravelled%20Series/) book, it looks like the address should be **&hd7b8**. The address in the original question is not actually a hex address. Sadly I don't have a disk drive to verify this on. [![disk basic unravelled](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qmIqU.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qmIqU.jpg)

Comment: I just copied it straight from the [linked](http://sparksandflames.com/files/HotCoCo-1983-07.pdf) website - and looking at it now, it's not even a Hex value! I feel ripped off...

Comment: Or [&HD66C](http://www.coco3.com/community/1988/05/general-information-4/#comment-43902). Or maybe [&HD66E](http://roust-it.dk/coco/disk-basic-unravelled.pdf#page=67).